# MVVM - User Control with ItemSource: init correctly but doesn't update value (but if I clear() it... yes!)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, mvvm, user-controls

I made a user control where I have set the itemsource property, so I can use it with binding.

If I use my control within a VB.NET project, it works perfectly. But, it doesn't when I try to use it from a C# one.

The weird thing is that I'm doing the same things and, further, if I use a standard WPF control in the C# projects, it works again.

Why does it work in VB.NET and not in C#? is it a random issue or are there any logical step to solve this?

This is how I manage the item source in my custom object:

```
Public Property ItemsSource() As IEnumerable
    Get

        Return DirectCast(GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty), IEnumerable)
    End Get
    Set(value As IEnumerable)
        SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly ItemsSourceProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", GetType(IEnumerable), GetType(DockGroup), New PropertyMetadata(New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)))

Private Shared Sub OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(element As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim c As DockGroup = DirectCast(element, DockGroup)
    Dim o = TryCast(element, DockGroup)
    If Not (o Is Nothing) Then
        c.OnItemsSourceChanged(e.OldValue, e.NewValue)


    End If

End Sub


Private Sub OnItemsSourceChanged(oldvalue As IEnumerable, newvalue As IEnumerable)
    Dim oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged As INotifyCollectionChanged = oldvalue
    If Not (Nothing Is oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged) Then
        RemoveHandler oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged, AddressOf newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged
    End If
    Dim newValueINotifyCollectionChanged As INotifyCollectionChanged = newvalue
    If Not (Nothing Is newValueINotifyCollectionChanged) Then
        AddHandler newValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged, AddressOf newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged

        aggiorna(newvalue)

    End If
End Sub
```

And this is my binding from the C# project:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel x:Name="pnl_serbatoi" Margin="0" >
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
            <CustomStack:DockGroup x:Name="pnl_serb" ItemsSource="{Binding serbatoiHomePage}" Orientation="HorizontalGroupLeft"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

And this is my "serbatoiHomePage":

```
    private ObservableCollection<isCtlSerbatoiWPF.isCtlSerbatoi.SerbatoioTMS> p_serbatoiHomePage;
    public ObservableCollection<isCtlSerbatoiWPF.isCtlSerbatoi.SerbatoioTMS> serbatoiHomePage
    {
        get { return p_serbatoiHomePage; }
        set { 
            p_serbatoiHomePage = value;
            base.RaisePropertiesChanged("serbatoiHomePage");
        }
    }
```

SerbatoioTMS is another user control I've made; it draws a little oil tank to show how it is full/empty.

Tell me if I can add more details for this issue.

**UPDATE**: from the C# project, if I use the debug mode step-by-step, when I set a new itemSource collection, it doesn't enter in the VB.NET code of the user control. If I use it in a VB.NET project, the step-by-step debug follows the correct flow.

**UPDATE2**: this is how I refresh data inside my serbatoiHomePage

```
void populateSerb() 
{
    var serbatoi = new ObservableCollection<isCtlSerbatoiWPF.isCtlSerbatoi.SerbatoioTMS>();
    [stuff here]
    [other stuff]
    serbatoiHomePage = new ObservableCollection<isCtlSerbatoiWPF.isCtlSerbatoi.SerbatoioTMS>(serbatoi.OrderBy(x => x.Serb_Impianto).ThenBy(x => x.Serb_Numero));
}
```

**VERY IMPORTANT UPDATE 3**: *The first binding works. I mean, when I init the app data values, the binding is correct. The probelm is the update of the binded data. In this case, it's like I don't make any update*.

**UPDATE4**: The itemsource property of my user control is updated only when I call the clear method of the binded object, like this:

```
serbatoiHomePage.Clear();
```

why is in this way triggered the change property? and why not in this other way?

```
serbatoiHomePage = new ObservableCollection<SerbatoioTMS>(serbatoi.OrderBy(x => x.Serb_Impianto).ThenBy(x => x.Serb_Numero).ToList());
```

Comment: In your C# project are you referencing the VB control project, or the dll created from the VB control project?

Comment: I've tried both. Now I'm referencing the dll, but I can switch if you say it can be useful. If it is for the debug, I say you that the itemSourceChanged doesn't even trigger.

Comment: @simonatrcl any idea? I'm stucked here and I really don't know how to solve this issue

Comment: One problem is that with 2 languages I think you have to reference the dll not the vb project. Not unreasonably, debugging 2 languages is not supported. However, you could put a write to the Console in the vb project which should allow some tracking.

Comment: @simonatrcl I have converted the user control in C# but the result is the same..

Comment: please, look the last update